# Python : Normalize Json response (array)

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am new to JSON and Python,I am trying to achieve below

Need to parse below JSON

```
{
    "id": "12345abc",
    "codes": [
       "BSVN1FKW3JKKNNMN",
        "HJYYUKJJL999OJR",
        "DFTTHJJJJ0099JUU",
        "FGUUKHKJHJGJJYGJ"
    ],
    "ctr": {
        "source": "xyz",
        "user_id": "1234"
    }
}
```

Expected output:Normalized on "codes" value

```
ID~CODES~USER_ID
12345abc~BSVN1FKW3JKKNNMN~1234
12345abc~HJYYUKJJL999OJR~1234
12345abc~DFTTHJJJJ0099JUU~1234
12345abc~FGUUKHKJHJGJJYGJ~1234
```

Started with below ,but need help to get to my desired output.

The "codes" block can have n number of values separated by comma.

The below code is throwing an error "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import json
import csv


f = open('rspns.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter = '~')
headers = [‘ID’,’CODES’,’USER_ID’]
default = ''
writer.writerow(headers)

string = open('sample.json').read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)

#print json_obj['id']
#print json_obj['codes']
#print json_obj['codes'][0]
#print json_obj['codes'][1]
#print json_obj['codes’][2]
#print json_obj['codes’][3]
#print json_obj['ctr’][‘user_id']

for keyword in json_obj:
    row = []
    row.append(str(keyword['id']))
    row.append(str(keyword['codes']))
    row.append(str(keyword['ctr’][‘user_id']))
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `json_obj` looks exactly like that , that is it is a dictionary, then the issue is that when you do -

```
for keyword in json_obj:
```

You are iterating over keys in `json_obj`, then if you try to access `['id']` for that key it should error out saying `string indices must be integers` .

You should first get the `id` and `user_id` before looping and then loop over `json_obj['codes']` and then add the previously computed `id` and `user_id` along with the current value from `codes` list to the `writer` csv as a row.

Example -

```
import json
import csv

string = open('sample.json').read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)

with open('rspns.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter = '~')
    headers = ['ID','CODES','USER_ID']
    writer.writerow(headers)

    id = json_obj['id']
    user_id = json_obj['ctr']['user_id']

    for code in json_obj['codes']:
        writer.writerow([id,code,user_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to iterate through `json_obj` as that is a dictionary and iterating through will get the keys.  The `TypeError` is caused by trying to index into the keys ('id', 'code', and 'ctr') -- which are strings -- as if they were a dictionary.

Instead, you want a separate row for each code in `json_obj['codes']` and to use the `json_obj` dictionary for your lookups:

```
for code in json_obj['codes']:
    row = []
    row.append(json_obj['id'])
    row.append(code)
    row.append(json_obj['ctr’][‘user_id'])
    writer.writerow(row)
```